# Retrofit Post Multipart form data values are empty

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, multipartform-data

I am trying to post some multipart form data via Retrofit in Android to a web service.
The web services's API expects the following parameters to be passed as field of a multipart form data:

```
Name         Type
company_id   text/plain
image        image/*
```

It also expects an authorization token to be passed as a query string parameter.

So i have defined my API interface call like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/companies/uploadImage")
@Headers({
"Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
"Accept: application/json"
})
Call<ServerResponse> companyUploadImage( @Part("company_id") RequestBody companyId, @Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Query("token") String token);
```

Afterwards this is how i call the above API interface method in a custom class:

```
RequestBody companyId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), LocalStorage.getInstance().getCompanyId());
File file = new File(postPath);

MultipartBody.Part image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));
                                       
Call<ServerResponse> uploadProfileImage = router.companyUploadImage(companyId, image, token);

uploadProfileImage.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {

       Log.e("Upload Profile Image: ", response.body().getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
       Log.e("Upload Profile Image Error: ", t.getMessage());
  }
});
```

The request is sent successfully to the server, so no networking exceptions occur, however the multipart form values, company_id and image, are received empty on the server side

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: `RequestBody companyId` Dont call a request bidy a company id. Unreadable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. It seems that the solution was as simple as removing the @Header annotation from the API interface method. So now it looks like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/companies/uploadImage")
Call<ServerResponse> companyUploadImage( @Part("company_id") RequestBody companyId, @Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Query("token") String token);
```

Maybe someone will find this post helpful.